# Restrict iTunes smart playlist to audio only

Tags: itunes, podcasts, playlists

I have a smart playlist of my favorite podcasts which I use for commuting -- it's mostly a simple collection of "Album contains [This Week in Tech](http://twit.tv/twit)" or "Album contains [Croncast](http://croncast.com)", etc.

The feed from [The Radio Adventures of Dr. Floyd](http://www.doctorfloyd.com/) sometimes includes video episodes. I want to edit my smart playlist so that the video episodes aren't included so that I don't get tempted to look over at my iPhone while driving.

I've tried removing "Media Kind is Music Video" and "Media Kind is Movie" but these appear to have media kind as "podcast" -- just like the audio only episodes.

Anybody know a way to tell the iTunes 9 smart playlists to include only audio files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove where Kind is video and video kind is movie. That will take care of your problems.

Comment: aha -- kind contains "video". Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to add "movie" as well. Otherwise you won't get them all.

Answer (score 0):

Also, iTunes 9 has a Media Kind field, which you can filter to Music - that would seem to be the best way now, and you can also set it to specific kinds of audio and video. It will correspond to the "library" your media falls into (except Music Videos, which still show up under Music).

Comment: The podcasts have media kind = "podcast" regardless of content.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry.